# Rails: Uninitialized constant - can not access to another class from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service-object

**search_handlers_controller.rb**

```
class SearchHandlersController < ApplicationController
  def match 
    @string = 'string'        
    @result = case params['search_style']
    when 'match'
      MatchService.call(@string)    
      ...
```

**MatchService.rb in /services:**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class MatchService < ApplicationService
  ...
  def call(string)
    'Match'
  end
end
```

**Error when calling MatchService from SearchHandlersController#match:**

```
NameError (uninitialized constant SearchHandlersController::MatchService):
app/controllers/search_handlers_controller.rb:18:in `match'
```

Comment: you named the file is `MatchService.rb`, didn't you?

Comment: Did you tried restarting your server??? whenever the service service file created you have to restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you named the file `MatchService.rb`, you should change name of this file into `match_service.rb`.

If this isn't work in your case, you can always call the service from the root by add `::` before the service name like that: `::MatchService.call(@string)`.

I hope it helps you!